# how to Changing Button Text in Android using soft keyboard?

Tags: android

How to enter text in button using soft keyboard.So by pressing button the softkeyboard will open and user enter text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use edittext having style type button. see the below code in XML

```
<EditText
            android:id="@+id/buttonedittext"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"                
            android:text="test"
            style="@android:style/Widget.Button" />
```

i display like button and also when you click on it display soft keyboard and you can type anything that you want.

Hope useful to you :)

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void showKeyboard(View view)

{

    InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager)myContext.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

    mgr.showSoftInput(view, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);

    ((InputMethodManager)myContext.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)).showSoftInput(view, 0);

}
```

This code is to open a softkeyboard. You can put this in  your Button's onClick. But I am not sure about typing on a button.I am coming across this for the first time.Why are you not using editText for it?

Comment: As per client Requirement,need to enter text in button.not using edit text.